# Java Beginner Rental Program

Tags: java

I'm quite new to programming. I'm trying to make a program for a bike rental service. And the issue is that there are two tariffs (1 and 2) for a specific time.

Tariff 1 : 00:00 to 07:00 and 17:00 to 24:00. (1$)
Tariff 2 : 07:00 to 17:00. (2$)
I need to use the scanner, so I write the two numbers, and it must calculate me the number of hours in tariff 1 and tariff 2, as well as the total cost. The issue is that I have no idea how to write the program so it detects how much hours are the in one tariff or another.

The program must work the following way :

1. Input 1
2. Input 2
3. Calculate the amount of hours in Tarif 1 and 2, and give a total.
4. Give the total price.

So here's the code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bike {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner clavier = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Give the starting hour : ");
    int start = clavier.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Give the ending hour : ");
    int finish = clavier.nextInt();

    if (start < 0 || start > 24) { 
    System.out.println("Hours must be within 0 and 24 !");
    }
    if (start == finish) {
    System.out.println("Strange, you didn't take it long enough !");
    }
    if (start >= 24 || start > finish) {
    System.out.println("Strange, the starting hour is after the end ...");
    }
    int total = finish - start;
    if (total > 0) {
    System.out.println("You have rented the bike for " + total + " hours.");
    }
//This is where it becomes complicated.

    if ((start >= 0 && start < 7)||(start >= 17 && start <= 23)) {
        System.out.println("Amount of hours in Tariff 1 is : " + ((7 - start) +(finish - 17)));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Amount of hours in Tariff 2 is : "
        System.out.print("Total amount to pay is : ");
        System.out.println(" dollars.");
        {

        }
```

Comment: It looks like you've asked [almost this exact question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51096689/how-to-let-the-program-know-which-is-the-tariff) where it was heavily downvoted and closed. Why do you expect it will be more well-received this time?

Comment: I've edited it, and just before, it was closed.

Comment: It's not exactly the same, but still "I have no idea how to write the program" is not a question, and is not considered on-topic here, sorry. Please see the help page [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com). You need to check for the finish too, where the finish is happening whether it's between the boundary of 1st tarrif or second tarrif. Don't think it as a coding issue and it needs logic rather then syntax. I think if you think properly you can figure it out. because this program will not require any java specific library so focus on logic and use finish time variable as well.

Comment: The problem is that I've tried. And still I do not know how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you're new to programming so I'm going to try and keep this simple. The issue here isn't syntax or some secret in java, its just missing logic. I can see from what you've written that you're either in high/middle school just starting programming or someone who has just started learning to code.

So I'm going to try and keep it simple and not give you too many hints.

You cannot have tariff 2 only in the else. I would recommend creating 2 ints, tariffOne and tariffTwo (or whatever names you like),make them = 0. Calculate them using some if statements. Then, when you have the values use them in the System.out.

This is good because you can add simply add whatever you want to the ints and you will always have their values.

The reason this question is being downvoted is because you've got all the tools to answer the question and you've just not got a grasp of the logic required, its not generally good practice to do this since it seems lazy, even if you've tried really hard.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll try that.